# Gmail offline on Firefox 4.0.1: "Offline Mail is not supported by your browser"

Tags: 11.04, firefox, gmail, offline

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 and its default browser Firefox 4.0.1.
A pretty standard configuration, so I am surprised that [Gmail offline](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=97551) cannot be configured and [tells me](https://mail.google.com/mail/#settings/offline):

> Offline Mail is not supported by your browser

Is it really the case? Or is there something I can do to be able to use Gmail Offline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Offline GMail uses Google Gears which
>   isn't available for Mozilla Firefox
>   4+, Internet Explorer 9+, and Google
>   Chrome on Mac or Linux.

See the complete system requirements [here](http://gears.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=79875)

Comment: It seems it's a requirement problem then... Googling around I discovered they'll switch off Gmail offline support for chrome on 5/24 but will keep working on Firefox 3.6. So definitely, the only solution is downgrade. Or install IE8 via wine :D

Comment: I had no idea that you could get [IE to run using wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=25)

Comment: Sounds weird, doesn't it? :) I've had some problems getting it to work actually, but it's useful if you have to debug html compatibility without needing launching a VM.

Comment: Yes, Google will be restoring offline support for Gmail and Google Docs any time now. It actually should have been ready by now, as Google Gears has been deprecated for a while I believe.

Answer (score 4):

Actually Gmail Offline is migrating from Gears to HTML5 so it's not working these days. You have to wait until Chrome12 to get the new updated Offline Service.

Answer (score 2):

Offline Gmail is now available for Ubuntu as an app through the Chrome Web Store: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ejidjjhkpiempkbhmpbfngldlkglhimk

[image]

(tested on Ubuntu 10.04, Chrome 13)

Comment: +1 Interesting! Just installed it on Chrome, it works well even though the interface seems to be touchscreen-oriented. However, it does not seem to download all messages, only the most recent ones (like the Android app), so it probably won't be helpful when offline looking for an email received years ago.